# Change form labels on hosted page

Tags: javascript

I am using Chargify to sell some subscriptions online.

They provided hosted pages where you can collect information that leads to the creation of a subscription and customer in their system.

Here's our form page here:
https://exponential-finance.chargify.com/h/3373511/subscriptions/new

As you can see, we'd really like to have those fields labeled "Billing Address" instead of "Shipping Address."

Alas, there is no way within Chargify to change those labels. However, the DO provide the ability to load javascript on the page.

I understand that it is theoretically possible to change HTML on a page using a script.

I've spent a couple hours attempting some scripts found online, but none do the job.

Here's an example of a label that I want to change:

```
<p class="left">
  <label for="subscription_customer_attributes_address">*  Shipping Address 1</label><br />
  <input id="subscription_customer_attributes_address" name="subscription[customer_attributes]
[address]" size="30" type="text" />
</p>
```

Can somebody point me to a script that would allow me to change the label text from "Shipping" to "Billing" for this field, and even better, for any instance of the word "Shipping?

Comment: I found a small typo I guess: "wife transfer" should be "wire transfer", right? ;)

Comment: LOL indeed. That's really funny. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, hope you get that going. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  window.onload=function() {
   var lab = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (i=0, l=lab.length;i<l;i++)
    {
     var old = lab[i].innerHTML;
     var news = old.replace(/shipping/i, 'Billing');
     document.getElementsByTagName('label')[i].innerHTML=news;
    }
  };
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2YABH/3/

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! But sadly this did not work.

Comment: @TomElliott Ok, I took the `window.onload` out, should work now, if it does not get triggered before DOM ready, hmmm.

Comment: @TomElliott Ok, I put the event in again. Should work, doesn't it? Added a jsFiddle...;)

Comment: Still no-go :( I've tested on a couple different browsers to no avail

Comment: Hmm, could you add a `alert('test');` in front of the `</script>` and confirm that you have a popup? I wonder if the script gets loaded at all?

Comment: No popup. I do see this little bit of code in lower left hand corner:

//]]>

Comment: hmm, looks like `CDATA`. Can you give us a screenshot? And how exactly are you uploading the script?

Comment: I can't explain it, but it is now working... I cut/pasted the code direct from your revision of the fiddle, and voila. THANK YOU!

Comment: HEHE, yeah!! ;-) I thought so, if you took it from the fiddle, you have no `<script>` tags, you must have had them twice. ;)

Comment: Weirdness. The "Add your custom javascript here" box doesn't specify if you do or do not need the script tag. I thought I had tried it both ways. No matter, it loads! (Albeit with a split second delay, but hey, who reads that fast anyway.)

Comment: Ah, well, yeah, that explains something. ;) If you want to try, you can take the `window.onload` line and the `};` out, and see if the delay is gone (and it is still working). ;)

Comment: I removed "window.onload=function()" but don't see a corresponding }; to delete; yet it works anyway, and yes is faster! Final version seen here: http://screencast.com/t/mNhkZMPHfB

Comment: Hmm, that works?!? You could take the first `{` and the `};` out I guess, am happy for you!!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Per your comments, it looks like you need to change ALL 6 INSTANCES.
You can do it easily with Javascript, jQuery or CSS.

With Javascript:

```
 //change a specific element
 document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML = "* Billing Address";

 //to change ALL INSTANCES:
 for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('left')[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = "* Billing Address";
}
```

[Javascript JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YABH/4/)

If you have jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.left > label').text('* Billing Address');//nth-child(6) will refer to the 6th element
});
```

[jQuery JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g7we/2/)

```
.left > label {color:transparent}
.left > label:before {color:#000;content:"* Billing Address";}
```

[CSS JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meBR4/9/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sadly, I don't have any control on whether or not jquery is available. Again, this is a hosted page on a third party service. I believe all I can do is enter custom css or run a script.

Comment: if you can run a script, you can probably include the jquery. Unless they specifically try to block it, which I doubt. I'll update my answer to include a solution with JS only.

Comment: @TomElliott working now, I added a native Javascript example and a CSS example :)

Comment: Unfortunately the ID "left" is assigned to all the fields in the left-half of this form... which means all the field names changed when the CSS was applied. 

I don't see any way to target to the six instances of "shipping" seen here: http://screencast.com/t/KbZZbsd0j

Seems to me that the targeting has to happen at the label level, or the script needs to find/replace on the word "shipping." @dollarvar's script appears to attempt such a find/replace, but isn't working either.

Comment: do you need to change ALL instances? or just the 6th one?

Comment: All instances of the word "shipping" need to be changed to "billing."

There are six fields with shipping:

Shipping Address 1
Shipping Address 2
Shipping Country
Shipping State
Shipping City
Shipping Zip Code

Shipping Address 1

Comment: I think I'm not being clear enough about the challenge- sorry! There are six instances of the word "shipping" in this form, with six related field labels. Some are in <p class="left"> and some are in <p class="right">. All are wrapped in a div class="section_two" if that helps! Here's the full HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/8yL6R/